# Laravel mail notification

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

With Laravel 5.3, I can define recipient in a `Notification`:

```
// In a class extending Illuminate\Notifications\Notification :

public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)->line('hello')->to('me@example.com');
}
```

Since Laravel 5.4 ([relevant commit](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/ff685491f4739b899dbe91e5fb1683c28e2dc5e1)), I can't use `to`. How can I update my code? I need to send a notification to an email which is not bound to a user nor an object. How to "hack" these missing functionality?

Comment: the object you send has to be Mailable
    return new Mailable($this->invoice)->to('me@example.com');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a minimal class with an email property:

```
class MyNotifiable
{
    use \Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

    public $email;

    public function __construct($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }
}
```

Then call `notify` on your minimal class:

```
(new MyNotifiable('me@example.org'))->notify(new MyNotification);
```

And it works.

Comment: I just need to show all in one, i.e does your solution in the notification class inside `toMail` method? i.e ` return(new MyNotifiable('me@example.org'))->notify(new MyNotification);` and how could implement it with an array of emails?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the master branch of the same file?

It has been reverted:

> https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Notifications/Channels/MailChannel.php

Also the documentation has `to()`

```
use App\Mail\InvoicePaid as Mailable;

/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return Mailable
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new Mailable($this->invoice))->to($this->user->email);
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks. It's about `MailMessage`, not `Mailable`. `to()` is still not present in https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Notifications/Messages/MailMessage.php

Comment: I hope you are looking for `replyTo()` It is over here : https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Notifications/Messages/MailMessage.php#L118